# user is not eligible to this purchase for android inapp purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have developed **InApp purchase** for Android app.

My **APK is signed** and uploaded into developer console and create one subscription product this product also Published ,my APK in draft mode and create one test mail account.

If i used test products its working fine but when i used real products its showing

> `User is not eligible to this purchase error`

but in background showed  product description and product name.

I am using Test Mail ID as primary mail id of my Device also, but still it showing same error.
I Google someone said accessing APK take little bit time but I had uploaded my APK 2 days back still showing same Error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i solved above problem my eclipse upgrade InApp billing version 2 to InApp billing Version 3.

But i am using Inapp billing version 2 related code so its showing this error.

when i degrade InApp billing Version code 3 to 2 it's working fine.